# Maven and intellijIDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Today I found disattached maven libraries in IDEA project, [image]

went through file->settings->pluggins, marked disbundled 'maven', restarted IDEA. Nothing
changes. Json etc still reddish. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `disattached maven libraries` cause there are no maven libraries only dependencies of your project?

Comment: There were no mark near the maven:bundled (see pic above). Actually, I deleted sources yesterday and pulled from Github them again. That forced me to rejoin maven to the project. Sorry for not correctly asked question, I meant "lost maven dependency"

Answer (score 0):

I’ve configured the project by adding a new Maven module and copied the pom.xml file into it once again. Now it works fine.

More information on how to convert a project to Maven is described in the documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/convert-a-regular-project-into-a-maven-project.html